# bug in function (?) and I don't understand

Tags: c

I have structure

```
typedef struct StructString {

    void **string;

    ringinfo RingInfo; // now i dont use it

} StructString;
```

I use it

```
StructString str;
```

now I try to give my `str.string` value with random

```
int n = 1 + rand() % 30;
printf("%d\n", n);
str.string = RandomInput(str.string, n);
printf("%s\n", *(char **)str.string);
printf("%d\n", strlen(str.string));
```

the RandomInput func is here

```
void **RandomInput(void **s, const int n) {
    int i;
    s = malloc((n+1) * sizeof(void *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        char c=rand()%128;
        printf("%c ", c);
        s[i]=&c;
        printf("%d ", i);
        printf("%c\n", *(char *)s[i]);
    }
    s[n]='\n';
    return s;
}
```

and I have two problems:

1. sometimes there is "" char (use the screenshot)
2. `str.string` not what it should be (we can understand what it should be using the screenshot)
   [image]

help me please, I don't understand

Comment: you are printing unprintable ASCII values. https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `s[i]=&c;`, but c is a local variable.  Every pointer in `s` points to the same place, and that address is invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401729/bug-in-fuction-and-i-dont-understand#comment126206692_71401729 aaaa, thanks. didnt know there are unprintable values in ASCII

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401729/bug-in-fuction-and-i-dont-understand#comment126206730_71401729 how can i fix it?

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401729/bug-in-fuction-and-i-dont-understand#comment126206730_71401729** how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As the printable ascii characters are ranged between 0x20 (whitespace)
  and 0x7e (tilda), you can randomly pick one with `rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1) + ' '` or `rand() % 95 + 32`.
- If you do not have a specific reason, it will be better to define
  the data type of string as `char *`, not `void **`. Otherwise
  the assigned sequence of characters may have gaps between characters.
- You need to terminate the string `s` with a null character instead of
  a newline.

Then the rewrited code will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct StructString {
    char *string;
//  ringinfo RingInfo; // now i dont use it
} StructString;

char *RandomInput(char *s, const int n)
{
    int i;
    s = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char)); // strictly we should check the return value
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        char c = rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1) + ' ';
                                        // pick a printable character between ' ' and '~'
        printf("%c ", c);
        s[i] = c;
        printf("%d ", i);
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    }
    s[n] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    StructString str;
    int n = 1 + rand() % 30;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    str.string = RandomInput(str.string, n);
    printf("%s\n", str.string);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(str.string));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have said `char c = rand() % '~' + ' ';` rather than use magic numbers

Comment: @pm100 thank you for the suggestion. I do agree! But it should be `rand() % ('~' - ' ' + 1) + ' ';`, isn't it :)

Comment: yes, I didnt read in detail

Comment: @pm100 thank you for the prompt reply. I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: @tshiono big thanks! but i should use void **. it is my task string with void* elements. how to be with it? my friend helped me, he said i should use not `char c`, but char `*c = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` and it works, but my string remeber olny first element

Comment: As your `string` is defined as `void **`, the size of each element is 4 byte (32bit arctecture) or 8 byte (64bit architecture). The char data will be assigned to every 4 byte or 8 byte even if you cast it to (char *). You can check it with `printf("%d\n", sizeof(*s));`. You will need to write your own `printf()` and `strlen()` to read `string` correctly (picking every 4 or 8 bytes).